# How to move the icon / button outside the textbox x-webkit-speech?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-chrome

i have it[image]

i want it
[image]

my code html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
</body>
</html>
```

How I can do to move it with css, html or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS:

```
.myclass::-webkit-input-speech-button{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0, 0.0);
    margin-right: 0px; //here for move icon example: margin-right: -10px
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

.myclass:hover::-webkit-input-speech-button, .cajasmodales:focus::-webkit-input-speech-button{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
    margin-right: 0px; //here for move icon example: margin-right: -10px
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

In the HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input class="myclass" type="text" x-webkit-speech />
</body>
</html>
```